# Accessing ballerina record nil fields in runtime

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to access a ballerina record fields in runtime by enumerating through them. However there I couldn't figure out to get access to the nil fields as it seems I can only access the fields that has values.

[image]

```
public type Segment record {
    string name;
};

public type MSH record {
    *Segment;
    string name = MSH_SEGMENT_NAME;
    ST msh1?;
    ST msh2?;
    HD msh3?;
};
```

Consider the "segment" record(it's record type of MSH). As you can see (look for debug variables) I can only access the keys and entries those have values. I currently enumerate through the fields using **entries()** method from the record instance. Is there a way that I can access the record fields with nil values as well from a runtime logic?

Comment: What is the definition of the `segment` type? Also, better to provide code as a code segment rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @ThisaruG it's a defined record type. updated the question with the record definition

Answer (score 3):

In your `MSH` record type, the `name` field is the only mandatory field. The others are optional fields. There is no way the compiler can know whether an optional field exists or not in the runtime.

If you need to access the values of the optional fields, you can access them as follows:

```
public function getSegmentField(int fieldNum, int repetitionNum, hl7v23:Segment segment) returns anydata {
    ST? msh1 = segment?.msh1;
}
```

Notice the type of the field is either `ST` or `nil`. If the field doesn't exist, the value of the `msh1` will be `nil`.

The `keys()` method returns the fields that are available at the runtime. If it does not include a field, that means the field does not exist.

You can refer to [this example](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/optional-fields/) for more information about optional fields.